# Unlinked .cs files impact on application performance

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a very simple question. Lets suppose there is `C# project` name `Game` and in this project there are two `.cs` files, `PacMan.cs` and `Snake.cs`. I copied both these files and pasted them in the same folder where `Snake.cs` and `PacMan.cs` resides. If I build the project, does unlinked files present in the folder have any effect in application `performance`? I am confident that compiler gonna ignore unlinked files and there wouldn't be any performance impact, but I am not 100% sure. Can anybody comment on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files aren't included in the compile, so the resulting program has no knowledge of them and therefore performance won't be impacted.

Comment: What if .cs is included in the project, but class is not referenced in entire project?

Comment: If there are no references to any of the classes in the .cs file, then the class won't be loaded by the runtime. Remember, the JIT compiler only loads and compiles those things that are actually referenced.